# Generating numpy arrays for scikit linear regression model

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a large dataset with multiple variables: item, location, quality (scale of 1-10), and a range of dates containing "no" if the item did not sell that day and the price if it did sell that day.

I want to create a linear regression model to be able to predict the price given a location and quality. I read through the scikit-learn tutorials, but I'm really confused as to what my input should be for the fit. Can someone help me out?

Comment: How is location represented?  As a 1-10 "quality of location" figure?  As lat/long values?

Comment: Location is represented by a zip code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your data to a numeric representation that models can work with. The only problematic feature is the location (categorical variable), but we can represent it with one column for each location, and 0s and 1s (so called OneHotEncoding). An example to get you started:

#### Preprocessing

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

data  = [
        {'location': 'store 1', 'quality': 8},
        {'location': 'store 1', 'quality': 9},
        {'location': 'store 2', 'quality': 2},
        {'location': 'store 2', 'quality': 3},
        ]
prices = [100.00, 99.9, 11.25, 9.99]
vec = DictVectorizer()
X = vec.fit_transform(data)
y = prices
```

Now `X` will look like this:

```
╔═════════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════╗
║ location=store1 ║ location=store2 ║ quality ║
╠═════════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════╣
║               1 ║               0 ║       8 ║
║               1 ║               0 ║       9 ║
║               0 ║               1 ║       2 ║
║               0 ║               1 ║       3 ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════╝
```

#### Model training

This matrix can now be feed to a model:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
```

#### Prediction

The new data will also need to be converted into numeric form using the same `DictVectorizer`. Note that now we use `.transform` instead of `.fit_transform`:

```
>>> test_data = [{'location': 'store 2', 'quality': 3}]
>>> X_test = vec.transform(test_data)
>>> model.predict(X_test)
array([ 10.28])
```

By the way, I would approach this problem as a classification problem(sold/not sold) and then I would use regression to determine the price only on the sold items.

Comment: What is "y" in the model training, and how can I associate "prices" with a particular location/quality?

Comment: `y = prices` and the association is by index, i.e. the first item in the data list corresponds to the first item in the prices list, `data[2]->prices[2]`, and so on. BTW if the location is a zip code I would convert it to string, so that the Dictvectorizer handles it as a Categorical and not a Numerical variable.